# PHP Character encoding between strings and filenames

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a file of poorly written html (exported from a Windows program so I have no control over it) that I want to parse. I'm using regex which I know isn't great for HTML but I know that the structure won't change so it works just fine.

The data looks like this:

http://pastebin.com/2dx1G271

At first file_get_contents wasn't working but Firefox told me it was encoded as UTF-16. So I encoded it like so:

```
$shortlist_html = mb_convert_encoding(file_get_contents($this->html_loc), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16');
```

I then get the data I want from between the td's however sometimes the data has a strange character like this (note the strange i):

> Ademílson

However I also have a directory full of images which I want to loop through and they have names like this:

> Ademílson_ Attributes.png
>
> Ademílson_ Stats.png
>
> Ademílson_ Profile.png

Now I want to match the name against the image name. I can get the name with regex easily but then a straight match doesn't work. If I var_dump the string I get:

> Adem�lson

And if I utf-8 encode it and then var_dump it, it has stripped the "í"

> Ademlson

Neither of the above will match my string.

I should note that when I say match, what i'm actually doing is an isset e.g:

```
$myarray = array('Ademílson'=>57);

$handle = opendir($image_dir);
while($filename = readdir($handle)) //$filename is Ademílson_ Attributes.png
{
     preg_match('/(.*?)_+/', $filename, $matches);
     
     $playername = $matches[1]; //$playername is Ademílson but appears as Adem�lson when using var_dump
     
     if(isset($myarray[$playername]))
     {
          //This never matches
     }
     
     foreach($myarray as $name => $id)
     {
          if($name == $playername)
          {
               //This never matches
          }
     }
     
     //Okay try and utf-8 it instead
     $playername = mb_convert_encoding($playername, 'utf-8', mb_detect_encoding($playername)); //This time a var_dump strips the "i" e.g. Ademlson
     
     if(isset($myarray[$playername]))
     {
          //This still never matches
     }
     
     foreach($myarray as $name => $id)
     {
          if($name == $playername)
          {
               //This still never matches
          }
     }
}
```

I hope i've explained that sufficiently. Basically I want to match a string retrieved from a filename to a string retrieved from the contents of a file, when the string contains unusual characters.

Comment: 1) Do you send encoding headers before var_dumping the string? If not, that could be the reason for having the misleading «�» instead of «í». So in your isset() or foreach() routines you still should check for «í».
2) You need quotes to check for array keys. isset($myarray['Ademílson']);

Comment: Sorry that was just pseudo code. Obviously the isset is using a variable. Maybe I should update it.

Comment: Okay @andr i've edited the code in the question sending headers and not using quotes isn't the problem, since that was just pseudo code :)

Comment: I think you might need to use the PHP mb_ function set e.g. mb_ereg_replace http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace.php

Comment: Can you be more specific? I can't see how an mb_ereg_replace would help me and mb_ereg_match doesn't seem to work the same as preg_match so that can't be what you're getting at.